# How to set initial value from a model's custom field in a ModelForm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-countries

I want the PestReport country to be automatically set in the ModelForm but keep getting the following error using the code below:

```
TypeError at /countries/italy/pestreports/create/
pest_report_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'country'
```

I will also eventually need to make sure that the user can only add pest reports of a country that is the same as their profile's country. I'm using [django-countries](https://bitbucket.org/smileychris/django-countries/).

**How can I set the URL's  keyword argument to the form automatically (the user should not be able to select the country) in the code below?**

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .ippc.views import pest_report_create

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    # pest report add
    url(r'^countries/(?P<country>[\w-]+)/pestreports/create/$',
        view=pest_report_create,
        name='pest-report-create'),
)
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class IppcUserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User")
     country = CountryField(_("Country"))

class PestReport(models.Model):
    country = CountryField(_("Country"))
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="pest_report_author")

class PestReportForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = PestReport
```

**views.py:**

```
from .models import UserProfile, PestReport, PestReportForm
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, redirect

def pest_report_create(request):
if request.method == "POST":

    form = form(request.POST, instance=PestReport())

    user = request.user
    author_id = user.id

    profile_user = request.profile_user
    country = profile_user.country

    if form.is_valid():
        new_pest_report = form.save(commit=False)
        new_pest_report.author_id = author_id
        new_pest_report.country = country
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')
else:
    form = form(instance=PestReport())
return render_to_response('countries/pest_report_create.html', {'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**UPDATED views.py function (now works) thanks to [Peter Tinkler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2539296/pete-tinkler)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17829088/412329):**

```
def pest_report_create(request, country):

    user = request.user
    author = user
    country=user.get_profile().country

    form = PestReportForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            new_pest_report = form.save(commit=False)
            new_pest_report.author = request.user
            new_pest_report.author_id = author.id
            form.save()
            return redirect("pest-report-detail", country=country, year=new_pest_report.publish_date.strftime("%Y"), month=new_pest_report.publish_date.strftime("%m"), slug=new_pest_report.slug)
    else:

        form = PestReportForm(initial={'country': country}, instance=PestReport())

    return render_to_response('countries/pest_report_create.html', {'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**countries/template/pest_report_create.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}

<form class="customform" method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL has a parameter:

```
(?P<country>[\w-]+)
```

that it is trying to pass to your view, but your view isn't accepting that parameter.

```
def pest_report_create(request):
```

should be

```
def pest_report_create(request, country):
```

You'll then want to pass the country across in the initial data for the form:

```
form = PestReportForm(inital={'country': country}
```

I'd also recommend not defining your forms in the models module

Comment: Thank you! I also managed to get the user's profile country used as the default using the updated views.py code (see UPDATE in the question), and also moved the PestReportForm code to forms.py.